# Regular expression in my simple case

Tags: java, regex

I would like to have a regular expression which validates if a string is in the format that it **starts with # which is followed by random numbers (the length is unlimited), the spaces between numbers are arbitrary too**.

For example, **#31 5 2 0000 12**

I come up with the regular expression `^[\\#][0-9]$` , but seems it is wrong. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you allow for multiple consequent spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical use case of the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern:

```
^#\d+(\s+\d+)*$
# as a Java string:
"^#\\d+(\\s+\\d+)*$"
```

Note: if you use `.matches()`, which is really misnamed in Java, you can remove the `^` and `$` anchors since they will be automatically inserted. Real pattern matching in Java is done with `.find()` (which `String` does not have, but which `Matcher` has)

Note 2: this will not allow trailing spaces; if there can be trailing spaces, change to:

```
^#\d+(\s+\d+)*\s*$
# as a Java string:
"^#\\d+(\\s+\\d+)*\\s*$"
```

Comment: I would change the last `\d+` to `\d*` since we don't know if the number can end with spaces (also in Java the `\\` have to be doubled in a string)

Comment: Well, the OP does not say, so by default I say they're not allowed ;) But if trailing spaces were allowed I'd just add `\s*` before the end-of-input anchor.

Comment: I tried it in Java code, I got error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: @Mellon this is normal, I write the regex in its "canonical" form here. In a Java string you need to double all backslashes: a backslash `\\` is written "\\" in a Java string

Comment: Thanks, could you please check another question which is quite related with this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962527/extract-sub-string-from-a-string

Answer (score 2):

`^[\\#][0-9]$` will match a single digit followed by `#` sign. You need

```
^#\d+(\s+\d+)*$
```

The Posix format will allow any other languages characters too.

```
^#[[:digit:]]+([[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+)*$
```

Note: This is a valid regular expression. You might need to tweak a bit to make compatible with java flavour.

Comment: could you please explain to me the meaning of \d and \s ? I can guess \d means digits.

Comment: \s means space characters. Like `\t\v\f\n `

Comment: This will allow trailing spaces though.

Comment: But now you won't match a single digit.

Comment: @Serious I think i have changed it before your comment

Answer (score 0):

Check this if you need at least on digit

```
^#\s*\d[\d\s]*$
```

- start
- hash
- optional spaces
- digit
- optional digits and spaces
- end

Answer (score 0):

^#(\d+\s?)*$

This accept #, #15, #2 14 52...
If you want to accept more than once space together change the ? with a *